# Issue with appDelegate methods

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I try to setup VK auth and FB auth in my project.

To setup FB auth I have to use following method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

To use VK auth I have to use the following method

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

   VKSdk.processOpenURL(url, fromApplication: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey)

return true

}
```

The problem is, that when I add VK auth FB stops working. If I comment method second method with call to VKSdk then facebook works just great

Comment: Have you tried to use the first method `application(application: openURL: sourceApplication: annotation)` and write there `VKSdk.processOpenURL...` then `return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance...`?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't compile, because of missing arguments

Comment: Which one is missing? You have both the application and the url :) Anyway, the solution from @Muneeba is better, as you call only 1 framework instead of both.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread. Yes, I tried this, then vk stops working

Answer (score 2):

Check url scheme in both cases, there should be different prefix for both url's scheme and put condition on that scheme to handle for both case. Like for Facebook scheme contains `fb`prefix followed by `FacebookAppId`

```
   let bundleInforDict:NSDictionary = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!

   if((url.scheme.hasPrefix(String(format: "fb%@", (bundleInforDict.objectForKey("FacebookAppID"))! as! String )))) {
        return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, withSession: FBSession.activeSession());
    }
    else{
         // Your VK auth work
    }
```

Comment: can not compile - says that FBAppCall and FBSession are unknown identifiers

Comment: you need to change it , that was as per my code. you replace  it with your code. The difference is due to different Facebook framework version.